# How to avoid Iterator method being restarted?

Tags: c#, linq, iterator, yield-return

Please consider the following C# block:

```
int resultIndex = 0;

Result firstResult = results.First();
DoAVeryImportOperationWithFirstResult(firstResult);

Console.WriteLine(String.Format("This is the {0} result.", resultIndex++));
yield return firstResult;

foreach(Result result in results)
{
   Console.WriteLine(String.Format("This is the {0} result.", resultIndex++));
   yield return result;
}
```

If you are familiarized with Linq and Iterators, you'll notice that in the first iteration of the `foreach` block, the first result from results will be returned instead of the second one.

So, basically this is my problem: I can't get the first value from the iterator method then use it somewhere else without restarting this method.

Someone know some workaround for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Others have shown the approach using a `foreach` loop and conditional execution. That's actually a neat approach - but here's another option in case the `foreach` loop is inappropriate for whatever reason.

```
using (var iterator = results.GetEnumerator())
{
    if (!iterator.MoveNext())
    {
        // Throw some appropriate exception here.
    }

    Result firstResult = iterator.Current;
    DoAVeryImportOperationWithFirstResult(firstResult);

    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("This is the {0} result.", resultIndex++));
    yield return firstResult;

    while (iterator.MoveNext())
    {
        Result result = iterator.Current;
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("This is the {0} result.", resultIndex++));
        yield return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Damn! Beat to it once again.

Answer (score 3):

Just do it explicitly:

```
bool first = true;
foreach(var item in results) {
    if(first) {
        first = false;
        // whatever
    } else {
        // whatever else
    }
}
```

or more complex:

```
using(var iter = results.GetEnumerator()) {
    if(iter.MoveNext()) {
        // do first things with iter.Current

        while(iter.MoveNext()) {
            // do non-first things with iter.Current
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to iterate manually:

```
var enumerator = results.GetEnumerator();
enumerator.MoveNext();
yield return enumerator.Current; //first
while(enumerator.MoveNext())
 yield return enumerator.Current; //2nd, ...
```

All error checking omitted... Also don't forget to dispose.

Answer (score 3):

```
bool isFirst = true;
foreach(Result result in results)
{
   if(isFirst)
   {
      DoAVeryImportOperationWithFirstResult(firstResult);
      isFirst = false;
   }

   Console.WriteLine(String.Format("This is the {0} result.", resultIndex++));
   yield return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Skip

```
foreach(Result result in results.Skip(1))
{
   Console.WriteLine(String.Format("This is the {0} result.", resultIndex++));
   yield return result;
}
```

or manually iterate over the results.

If you think about how iterators are implemented what you are seeing is indeed the expected behavior!

Comment: Note that doing this involves iterating the source sequence twice.  In many practical cases that's fine, but in the general case it's not.